# How to traverse loop through temp table to take out each column name in SQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have one temp table in sql.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temporary(ColumnNames varchar(100),IsActive varchar(100))

insert into #Temporary(ColumnNames,IsActive)
select  aa.Name,bb.IsActive  from tableAA aa join tableBB bb on aa.Id = bb.Id

ColumnNames IsActive 
Name           1
Description    1
Id             0
```

Now I want to traverse through each ColumnNames and pass that value to another select query
and take out its related value from another table using join if IsActive =1

for example, I did it in c# code I need to convert this code in SQL code

```
new string s1 
forloop(END OF ALL COLUMNS FROM #Temporary){
    if(isactive=0)
    concatinate  string s1 +=cloumnIndex[i]+','
    else
    concatinate  string s1 +='(select resourcetableValue from ResourcesTable as t where contry.'+cloumnIndex[i]+'=t.resourcetableKey),'
}

EXEC('select  '+string s1 +' from vwCountry as contry')
```

I need to create String s1 which will take out all column names from Temp Table and for loop else part will populate values using join and at the end EXEC statement executes all query at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 DECLARE @i  INT=1,
            @s1 NVARCHAR(max)=''

    WHILE(@i<=@@ROWCOUNT)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @s1+= CASE WHEN isactive=1 THEN '(select resourcetableValue .......<your condition>'
              ELSE ''
    from #temporary WHERE id=@i

    SET @i=@i+1
    END
    exec sp_executesql @S1
```

Comment: There isn't any huge advantage in using sp_executesql if you aren't also going to parameterize; also - something smells "off" about that use of `@@ROWCOUNT` - and this depends hugely on contiguous ids being available...

Comment: @Marc Gravell♦ i agree to 'sp_executesql'. regarding @@rowcount that was just to take the count from the table.user can even take the count() from table.

Answer (score 1):

To write your loop "as is" can be done with:

```
declare @s nvarchar(4000) = '';
select @s = @s + case IsActive when 0 then ColumnNames + ','
    else '(select resourcetableValue from ResourcesTable as t where contry.'
        + ColumnNames + '=t.resourcetableKey),' end
from #Temporary

exec ('select ' + @s + ' from vwCountry as contry')
```

you probably want to remove the last comma between the `select` and the `exec`, though

Comment: thank you so much getting `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @ashish you asked how to build the query; don't blame me that the query you asked for is wrong... it does exactly what you requested in the question

Comment: true :) no problem i will try to out from this error thanks :)

Comment: can you help me how can I remove `,` of last columnName ?

Comment: i have used LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1) :) thanks

Comment: will it traverse through all columns? loop is not needed is it?